# Download a file from database or save folder in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
$data = 'Here is some text!';
$name = 'mytext.txt';

force_download($name, $data);
```

This is simple bownload code bit I need to download from database or my save path folder.

I need a complete code in MVC codeigniter framework.
I upload a file in a database and a given path folder  i make a online job portal project of my final degree  i want to download a CV or file  but i cant to it plz help me .how i can download file from a database or a save folder.

and this code is not working plz send me complete code with model view controller.

```
function download($fid){
    $query= $this->db->get_where('files',array('fid' => $fid));

$row = $query->result();
header("Content-Type: ". $row[0]->type);
header("Content-Length: ". $row[0]->size);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $row[0]->name);

// Print data
echo $row[0]->content;

//Free the mysql resources
mysql_free_result($result);
//redirect('index.php/files/search/'.$fid);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Controller:

```
public function download($file)
{

$this->load->helper('download');
$name = $file;
$data = file_get_contents('./uploads/foldername/'.$file); 
force_download($name, $data); 
    redirect('index','refresh');
}
```

Comment: Thnx! bro for reply i use your code but it not download a file from db.

Comment: view:  <a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/index/download/'.$row->file); ?>">download</a> this code set in download format

Comment: it download but not a file that was i uploded in database or my given pat folder.
this code just download a simple html page or storage device icon. but not download a file in DOC,DOCx.or pdf format

Comment: it worked for me , a simple solution saved my precious time

Answer (score 1):

okay bro to make a simple download look at my code below.

here is my code:

**View**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(')?>assets/save_files/$s->file_name">Download</a>
```

first make a `foreach()` statement like this `foreach($result as $s)`

**explanation**:

the `$result` you must create a function inside your controller:

**Controller**

```
public function get_all_data()
{
 $data['result'] = $this->model->get_data(); // 
$this->load->view('index',$data); //past the data to the view
}
```

**Model**

```
public function get_data()
{
$query = $this->db->get('table_name');
return $query->result();
}
```

then use the anchor code above to download the file on where you save the file.

note:

- save_files is the folder.
- $s-> is the file name.

Comment: Thnx! bro for reply i use your code but it not download a file from db.

Comment: Please help i'm very woorried .how i can i download uploaded file from darabase OR also from folder.

Comment: This code are not a download any file it just fetch value from database

Comment: are you using blob data type in databas?

Comment: when file is uploded file name are saved  in database with extenxion like doc or pdf. i want to download which file that user is uploaded

Plzzzzzzzzzz help me

Comment: you want to know which user has that file when uploaded you should make on the database if the relation ship is many to many or one to many make a reference id like user_id = 1 has 3 upload so the database should be userid=1|upload_file=sample.text,userid=1|upload_file=sample.doc,userid=1|upload_file=sample.jpg

Comment: then call it from database like `Select * From table_name Where user_id=id`

Comment: try this link [http://code.runnable.com/Uha2YpCDyMQpAAJi/download-file-using-codeigniter]

Comment: thnx for this link but i m alredy use this and its work ,
but i download a file from database ..this link code are not downlaod from databae it just download a file ,,

Comment: np but one thing you cannot download the file in the database unless you use the blob data type. kindly upvote or check if the answer is satisfactory.

Comment: ok thnx but  if folder cantain more files and i want to download a particular file how can i download these file ....
thi link u give it download but those file which wite in a code
but i want to download file that i want to download

Comment: in order to download the file in the folder the name of the file must be same in the database example i have 2 files with the same name but the other one has (1) or (2) before the file type and you check the database the name is sample(1).docx and your folder has sample(1).docx then when you download the file it will get sample(1).docx it all about the name bro it must be unique or you can change the name when uploading it i would prefer to be hash the names.

Comment: thnx dear for reply but i not understand your answer 
listin this code in link u send me it just which file dowmload that write in 

code like bolow code $name ='a.pdf'; //here what ever file name i write it 

download 

public function upload() {
  $this->load->helper('download');
  $name = 'a.pdf';
  $data = file_get_contents("./file/a.pdf");
  force_download($name, $data);
 }

but this code just its worked fine but it download a file that name was a.pdf

Comment: ..but folder also contain more file like b.pdf c.docx and can i download these 

file
 ...mean how dynamically download file from db i write many code like given 

below answer code but its not working plz help how download which particular 

file that i want to download.

Comment: okay did you read the user guide for codeigniter the name is what you want to name it and the data is the source path file you want to download the from the $data = file_get_contents("./file/a.pdf") the a.pdf is the source file meaning when you want to download another file inside the file_get_contents should be another format like b.pdf or b.docx dont just stick like "./file/a.pdf" it is constant meaning you are downloading the same file back to back you should initialize the file name you want to download remember $name is the name you want to have the file it is like more a renamer.

Comment: yes  the same file download back to back how i download another file like b.pdf ...
without given a $name='b.pdf'; i give $name='a.pdf'; and it download back to back i it change,,, and i download file that i wish to download

Comment: okay bro  to download the different file use the code you used file_get_content in side the code would be `file_get_content('./file/'.$file_name_here)`  and the name you can use like this `$name = $file_name` and you can download the same file name with the same source file path if i where you make a function in order to download all your file.

Comment: i tried that with different download type either jpg, pdf, docx the only following i did'nt try is gif, excel, powerpoint but it can download pdf, doc, docx and image also rar

Comment: don't use download manager thou it seems codeigniter has problem in download manager

Comment: thnx...but i use this code it not a download a file in proper format ...it download a like storage dveice icon and it not opn in any format...i use this code that u write in commct but it not properly working,,,
i show u a my code see
public function upload1($file_name) {
    $this->load->helper('download');

    $data = file_get_contents'/file/'.$file_name);
    $name = $file_name;
    force_download($name, $data);
 } 
but this code not a download a file how i can download a other files

Comment: can you send me your email and i will send you a working code here is my email trevjeminico@gmail.com

Comment: arslan.khalil758@gmail.com
This is my email plz send me a code in working and save path forlder db backup etc...all those thing that related to file download plz send me complete code Thnx...

Comment: plus 1 for `$this->load->view('index',$data);` - actually using a view to send the output!